# Solidity: Extend an already deployed contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have the following Solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

contract Parent
{
    uint public number;
}

contract Child is Parent
{
    function setParentNumber(uint _number) public {
        number = _number;
    }
}
```

So when I deploy `Child`, I'm able to modify the `Parent`'s property `number`. So far so good.

**Question: Is is possible to extend an already deployed contract and access its public properties?**

Example:

1. `Parent` has been deployed separately to address `0x123456` and its property `number` now has value of `5`.
2. Now I want to deploy Child to a **separate address**, but I want to be able to set the `Parent`'s (on address `0x123456`) property `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contract (`Parent`) does not provide interfaces to mutate its data, other contracts cannot do it.

Otherwise modifying balances of accounts would be free game for everyone.

Comment: That's a fair point with the token balances. Thank you for explaining.